# How can I split commits in one pull request between two pull requests?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

How can I split commits in one pull request between two pull requests?

I tried to find such feature on GitHub, but I wasn't able to find even how to remove a commit from the pull request.

Comment: The `git cherry-pick` command can be used to copy a single commit from one branch to another. This is something you would do using the git command line tools on your local system, rather than using the GitHub web interface.

Comment: Are you working personally or in a team setting? On my team I would wait until one of the pull requests get approved then merged and then rebase my other PR branch with master (or whatever you use) before merging that one

Comment: In a team. The problem is that GitHub automatically put too many commits in the same branch into a single pull request. But I want to split the commits between 2 pull requests.

Comment: I'm reading this differently than everyone else. To clarify, in your current branch, do all the commits you want in the first PR come before all the commits you want in the second PR? (Can you easily draw a single line to delineate the set of commits for each PR?) Also, do both PRs already exist, or would you just want to create a second PR?

Comment: I want to create the second PR from the last commits, but they were automatically added to the first already existing PR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it's not possible. Separate branches should be used for separate pull requests.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have both branches locally, you can use cherry-pick (see `git cherry-pick --help`, perhaps use `gitk` judiciously to identify what you want) to add individual commits from one branch to the other.

Afterwards you can rewrite history (reorder commits, delete some, squash them together, fix them, ...) using e.g. rebase (`git rebase --help`). But be *very careful*, you can't undo rewriting later. It also leads to you having a different history than everybody else, they will have to force getting the rewritten history. I'd create a new branch off the tip of the branch to be mangled, if redoing that goes south you can go back to the original; else delete the original and rename the new one over it.

Comment: I used the same branch. So, should I always create separate branches for separate pull requests?

Comment: @Dmitry yes, each pull request is normally associated to a different, temporary branch (so-called "feature branch"). And it can be useful to name the branch at stake with some selected keywords, e.g. `add-dashboard`, `fix-bug-12`, `improve-doc`, etc.: this can even be "specified" by the development team in the form of a "Git branch naming convention". BTW when the pull request has been merged, GitHub will propose you to delete the source branch through a dedicated button.

Comment: That's a waste of time to create separate branches each time. Before this problem I was OK using the same branch.